# Css how to align my circles horizontally after a word

Tags: php, html, css, geometry

I would like to show circles for the different levels. For example, if the level is proficient, it will show 1 circle. I am able to show the circles according to their levels but the circle is vertically shown. I want it to show it horizontally.

```
for($a = 0; $a < $count; $a++)
    {
        $b = $languagelevel[$a][0];
        echo $b;
        if($languagelevel[$a][1] == "Proficient")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language'></div>";
            }
        }
        else if($languagelevel[$a][1] == "Good")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language'></div>";
            }
        }
        else if($languagelevel[$a][1] == "Very Good")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language'></div>";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language'></div>";
            }
        }

        echo "<br>";
```

This is my css code for the circle. It will show the circles vertically but i want it horizontally.

```
.language
        {
            border-radius: 50%;


            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 8px;

            background: #fff;
            border: 2px solid #666;
            color: #666;


            font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try `display:inline-block;` ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Nice @Epodax. I got it! it works thank you!:)

Comment: @Epodax  
hmm but do you know how to make all the circle start at the same line? Because some words like english and cantonese have different length so the circle will start at different position which does not look very nice

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `float: left;` on your `.language` class?

And with `margin-left` you can put some space between the circles.

Comment: Yes i tried that and it gives me the circle first before my language. Anyways i got it i use display:inline-block; Thank you!:)

Comment: hmm but do you know how to make all the circle start at the same line? Because some words like english and cantonese have different length so the circle will start at different position which does not look very nice.